# How to use other clustering methods for clustergram in Matlab's bioinformatics toolbox

Tags: oop, matlab, bioinformatics, hierarchical-clustering

EDIT: I figured it out. Just did not understand notation.

Hello,

Hopefully someone out there is familiar with the clustergram in the bioinformatics toolbox. I am interested in the graphical aspects of the function (the dendrogram/heat map), but am currently handicapped as it requires me to use Matlab's cluster() function. I would prefer to use my personal algorithm to cluster, and then allow Matlab to visualize this for me.

I have searched the code, but am woefully ignorant about object oriented programming in general, and Matlab's version in particular. Thus all I know is the function calls the line 'obj = obj.getclusters', but have no idea how to edit it this such that I use my own clustering algorithm instead of Matlab's.

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: I am specifically working on a new algorithm, hence why I have no need for pdist or linkage. The dendrograms are calculated outside the clustergram function. All I am using to create the dendrogram/heatmap is the clustergram function. My Bioinformatics toolbox is version 3.3

Really, all I am looking for here is what the hell does 'obj = obj.getclusters;' do? I am not a programmer and really am not familiar with OO. To me, that looks like we magically have clusters, as there is no function call. This is at line 304 of clustergram()

Comment: What kind of data you want to use for visualization? Do you calculate dendrograms outside of clustergram? Pdist and Linkage parameters are not enough? What is your version of MATLAB, Bioinformatics toolbox?

Comment: I agree with @yuk, we need more details. Also it would help if you post a simple working example with the functions you are currently using to generate a dendrogram/heatmap...

Answer (score 0):

First I have later versions of Bioinformatics Toolbox (3.4 and later), and for those versions `clustergram.m` file does not have the line `obj = obj.getclusters;`

Remember [CLUSTERGRAM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/bioinfo/ref/clustergram.html) in the class (not function as it was it older version). When you run `clustergram(data,...)` you actually run the constructor method of this class to create clustergram object. This object is `obj` variable. So when you run `obj = obj.getclusters;` you actually run `getclusters` method in clustergram class, which updates the object `obj`.

To get more details what `getclusters` method is doing look for a following line in methods block:

```
    function obj = getcluster(obj)
```

---

In the latest versions there is method `computeClusters` defined as

```
    function computeClusters(obj)
```

This method computes both dendrograms for rows and columns and updates the object. You can directly alter this function, of course, but I wouldn't recommend it. It's much better to develop separate functions for distance metric and linkage and use those functions to construct clustergram object.

If your algorithm does not use distance and linkage, please explain how it's suppose to build dendrograms. Does it create linkage matrix same as output of [LINKAGE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/linkage.html) function? Without such matrix I don't think you can use clustergram even for visualization only. Do you have an example how your clustergram should look like? May be you can use [Heatmap](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/bioinfo/ref/heatmapobject.html) class of other simpler functions like [IMAGE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/image.html) or [IMAGESC](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imagesc.html).